# Cut the shape (image) and paste in another sheet with custom ID

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem.

I would like to cut my shape and paste it on another sheet with the specified ID.
Next I want to cut from that target sheet and paste it in the mother sheet (move back).

My code looks as follows:

```
 Sub Location()
 ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox_Location1").Copy
 Sheets("Readme").Range("AA1").PasteSpecial
 Selection.Name = "Location"
 End Sub


 Sub Locationremove()
 Sheets("Readme").Shapes("Location").Cut
 ActiveSheet.Range("F7").PasteSpecial
 Selection.Name = "Textbox_Location1b"
 End Sub
```

However, I can't do it, because the shape changes the ID every time when pasted in the target sheet.
Is there a way to prevent its mother ID or at least the custom one?

The code below brings the same result

```
Sub Location()
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Textbox_Location1b").Copy
Sheets("Readme").Range("AA1").PasteSpecial
Sheets("Readme").Shapes(Sheets("Readme").Shapes.Count).Select
Selection.Name = "Textbox_Location1b"
End Sub
```

Comment: Avoid using `.Selection` and `ActiveSheet`. Use explicit references instead the way you have with the "Readme" worksheet.

Comment: I am not sure I understood which is your problem... What would you like to happen when you copy - paste it? What do you mean  referring to `ID`? What this `ID` is for your?

Comment: Basically I am writing the code, where I want to move the shape from one sheet to another and keep the ID the same. In another code, I want to move it back to my mother sheet.

Comment: But, why do you need this ID? It is allocated by Excel when a new shape is created. In documentation it is connected (theoretically) to the shape type, but in practice even this is not true. Sometimes you copy a rectangle and the copied shape is a picture, according to the allocated name... So, the question (for me) is **Why do you feel that this ID would be useful**? Excel increments this ID **each time you create a new shape on the specific sheet**.

Comment: Why don't you try to declare and identify the new shape in a different way? For instance, after copying of the shape, you can identify it in this way: `Dim shP As Shape`   
    `Set shP = Sheets("Readme").Shapes(Sheets("Readme").Shapes.Count)`. Your shape will always be the last created one...

Comment: I am going to repeat this code in another few sheets, that's why I need this ID.

Comment: Please believe me, you do not need a volatile ID! You cannot count on it! Please try explaining what you intend to do in those 'other few sheets'. Didn't the way i suggested above not help you? You can easily identify the copied shape INDEPENDENT OF ITS ID, which, anyhow it is different from paste to paste. It is controlled only by Excel, not by the user! You can use it only if you do not make changes on your shapes on the page. The new shape will automatically receive a new ID! This is the way Excel Works!